# How can I Resolve This error on Ionic 5 (

Tags: ionic-framework, arima

I am trying to workring with Arima on Ionic, but I get this error

[image]

Comment: delete node_modules and npm install again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete **node-modules** folder and **package-lock.json** from your project.
2. Run the below command on root project directory.

   npm install --force

and try running again.